# Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: jsf, mojarra

Opening the JSF page gives me the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Here is the JSF code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="master_c.css" library="css" />
        <title>Quotes</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body styleClass="venue product">
        <h:form>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="content">
                    <h2><a href="#"><img src="/Webify/static/image/venue-large.png" /></a></h2>
                    <ul id="calltoaction">
                        <li id="cta-map"><a href="#">MAP</a></li>
                        <li id="cta-download" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_share_btn"><a href="#">qmobile</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- calltoaction -->
                    <div class="sec-content">
                        <ul id="techspecs" class="mobile">
                            <li></li>
                            <li><img height="50" width="79" alt="QMobile Kâşif" src="/Webify/static/image/mac-universal.png" /><b>QMobile</b><br />Bahara<br />Pahli baar</li>
                            <li>Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum Lorem Ispum</li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- techspecs -->
                        <ul id="sc-reviews" class="mobile">
                            <li><a href="#"><img height="35" width="200" alt="Android" src="/Webify/static/image/text_android.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img height="35" width="200" alt="IPhone" src="/Webify/static/image/text_iphone.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img height="35" width="200" alt="BlackBerry" src="/Webify/static/image/text_blackberry.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Find More...</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- sc-reviews -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="prim-content">
                        <!-- Page Heading -->
                        <div id="sec-navigation">
                            <h3 style="margin-left: 10px;"></h3>
                        </div>

                        <div id="wall">
                            <!-- bricks end -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- wall end -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Sep 16, 2011 1:45:40 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/streamfaces.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2734)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2244)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:899)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:418)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Sep 16, 2011 1:45:40 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl throwIt
INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2734)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2244)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:899)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:418)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Sep 16, 2011 1:45:40 PM com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils renderHtmlErrorPage
WARNING: JSF1087: Unable to generate Facelets error page as the response has already been committed.
Sep 16, 2011 1:45:40 PM com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils renderHtmlErrorPage
SEVERE: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2734)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2244)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:899)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:418)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    ... 19 more
```

How is this problem caused and how can I solve it? I am using Mojarra 2.1.2.

Comment: Related: [IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[SOLVED]

It took days to diagnose this problem, but finally I am able to solve this problem.

It was actually `@ViewScoped` and it has a managed property DAO object which was not serialized. So after view is rendered, facelets also produce this exception, but JSF view already rendered and that's why this exception showed.

**Solution:** Make all objects serialized in `@ViewScoped` bean, and mark "transient" who are not serialized like in my case it was DAO object in JSF `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: What if you don't have any BEAN at all, just a single JSF page? That is my own situation.

Comment: @AardvocateAkintayoOlusegun Can you provide your xhtml code? of simple page & configs too ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072311/illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-commi

Answer (score 18):

The reason is that:

1. JSF stores the page component structure in `HttpSession`
2. If the page content is very large and the session has not been previously created, some response may have been written and the error above happens

So the solution is to create the session before the Facelet (/JSP) page is printed. An crude example could be like:

```
@PostConstruct
void initialiseSession() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
}
```

/napu

Answer (score 9):

I put this in my web.xml to solve the problem for one of my apps.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

What is weird though is that I have several other applications hosted on this same glass fish instance that doesn't require this voodoo in the web.xml.

I strongly want to believe this is not the solution, cos it doesn't make any sense to me why this particular app requires it and the others didn't. But for now it works.

Comment: I said it. After working for about two hours, Suddenly I started getting this error again. The above voodoo is not the solution obviously.

Comment: actually, what I noticed this error occurs on a particular page if the page is the first to load. If I load any other page before it, everything works fine. Since this page is also my index page, I created another index.html and use meta to redirect to the problematic page.....grrrrrrr another voodoo

Answer (score 2):

It was happening to me too.

I used to have Mojarra 2.1.13 and after updating it to 2.1.29 the problem solved itself, without any changes in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It happened this error to me also, but related with the creation of a custom error page. I've generated a simple error page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" encoding="UTF-8">
        <h:head>

        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <!-- start writing here your components -->
        </h:body>
    </f:view>

</html>
```

And I've configured `web.xml` to dispatch 404 errors to this page:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error_404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

When I try to provoke the error I bump over the same error.