# jsf and LinkedHashMap results in java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, serialization, jsf-2

In my DetailsBean class I use the javax.faces imports to make the bean viewscoped.
        @ManagedBean
        @ViewScoped
        public class DetailsBean{

```
    @EJB
    RepositoryService repBean;
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> folder;
    @Inject
    private ApplicationBean appBean;
    @Inject
    private UserBean userBean;
    }
```

When trying to access the bean though, I get the following stacktrace :

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1014)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1014)
```

I looked at the javadoc of LinkedHashMap and there it says it implements Serializable interface. Also there are only Strings in the map and they of course implement it too. I then tried to mark the map transient but this didn't change anything. Whats the problem here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761622/ejb-in-viewscoped-managedbean-causes-java-io-notserializableexception ,may be helpful :)

Comment: yes you nailed it! State saving was set to client because of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433575/cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has-been-committed) . This caused this error message which has nothing to do with the actual error --> Gotta love java-ee :)